# EXC_BAD_ACCESS upon accessing a static member?

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access, cocos2d-x, static-members

I've developed a game on Cocos2d-x v2 platform
I started on Android, after completely finishing the coding on Eclipse I used the same code on Xcode to create and iOS version.
After adding all the required libraries, I succeeded in compiling the code. However, the game hangs the moment it runs on an iOS device, although it runs without any problem on Android.
I tried both the emulator and an iPod, but I always get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing a static member from a static method. The static member would always point to 0x0!!
Here's an excerpt from the code:\

AppDelegate.cpp

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "NASEncData.h"
AppDelegate::AppDelegate()
{
    ep = NASEncData::sharedUserData();
}
```

NASEncData.h

```
namespace CocosNas
{
    class NASEncData : public CCObject
    {
public:
        static NASEncData* sharedUserData();

private:
        NASEncData();

        static void initXMLFilePath();

        static std::string m_sFilePath;
    }
}
```

NASEncData.cpp

```
#include "NASEncData.h"


NASEncData* NASEncData::sharedUserData()
{
    initXMLFilePath();

    // only create xml file one time
    // the file exists after the programe exit
    if ((! isXMLFileExist()) && (! createXMLFile()))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (! m_spUserData)
    {
        m_spUserData = new NASEncData();
    }

    return m_spUserData;
}

void NASEncData::initXMLFilePath()
{
    if (! m_sbIsFilePathInitialized)
    {
        m_sFilePath += CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWriteablePath() + NASENCDATA_XML_FILE_NAME;                  <----error happens here
        m_sbIsFilePathInitialized = true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: By any chance, is the instance of `AppDelegate` that the constructor is called for also a static variable?

Comment: in the iOS version, there's a main .mm file which defines the following:
static AppDelegate s_sharedApplication;
is that OK?

Comment: I think that could be your problem.

Comment: Read my answer below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on your question, your problem could be the initialization order of static data. To be more specific, I think it is possible that the static `AppDelegate` instance gets created and initialized before the static members in the `NASEncData`. And this problem could also explain the fact that you are seeing different behavior on different platform, because the initialization order of unrelated static data are compiler and linker dependent.

To fix this, you could change your `NASEncData` like this: (note that this is only one possible fix, although if the initialization order of statics is really your problem, I think this is the simplest and best solution, apart from redesigning your code so that you don't have to rely on static members.)

NASEncData.h

```
namespace CocosNas
{
    class NASEncData : public CCObject
    {
    public:
        static NASEncData* sharedUserData();

    private:
        NASEncData();

        static void initXMLFilePath();

        // Note how the stuff below this line have changed
        struct StaticData
        {
            std::string m_sFilePath;
            // Put other static members here
            //   (e.g. m_sbIsFilePathInitialized, m_spUserData, etc.)
            // Put a proper constructor here if needed
        };

        static StaticData & getStaticData ()
        {
            static StaticData s_data;
            return s_data;
        }
    }
}
```

NASEncData.cpp

```
void NASEncData::initXMLFilePath()
{
    if (! m_sbIsFilePathInitialized)
    {
        // Note the change in accessing m_sFilePath
        // You should access all your static members like this
        getStaticData().m_sFilePath +=
            CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWriteablePath() +
            NASENCDATA_XML_FILE_NAME;
        getStaticData().m_sbIsFilePathInitialized = true;
    }   
}
```

What this does in ensure that when you try and access your static member data, they have already been initialized. This happens because all your static member data are now defined inside a function as static, and for accessing them you have to call that function, and the compiler generates code to make sure that the first time that function is invoked (and only the first time) your data is constructed and initialized properly, which in turn means that the first time you actually try to access this data, whenever and wherever that may be from, your data is properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed an initialization problem I just had to move the code from the construction to bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() and it worked!

Comment: OK, but that sounds like a very case-specific fix. Remember that initialization order problems *can* be fixed for good in the design and in the implementation.

Comment: I do not think that it is a case specific fix.
Cocos2D-X is a well known platform, and I think that the solution I have mentioned would help a lot of people.

Comment: Well, you are of course correct. This does help everybody who uses Cocos2D-X on iOS, and probably even on other platforms. But since every serious C/C++ programmer does fall into the static-initialization-order trap once or even more in his career, a general fix should/would be applicable to most of them and in many more situations. The fix you've come up with is perfectly legitimate and applicable, but it does nothing to fix the *cause* of the problem. It only moves some code around so you don't run into it *for now*.